# Select by Attributes query ArcMap 10.5.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

I am trying to find capitals with a population between 200,000 and 300,000 and I do not know how to build the query correctly. Here is what I have, but it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the query below, you need to identify pop2007 field in 2nd parameter

```
POP2007 >=20000 and POP2009 <= 30000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this query as long as it is not a STRING:

```
POP2007 BETWEEN 20000 AND 30000
```

[image]